# What is the name for a table that keeps track of operations that have been performed on the database?

Tags: database-design

It's name is `Trans_Log`
It has the following fields:

- TL_User (database user logged in)
- TL_WinUser (name of windows user logged in)
- TL_Date (date of operation?)
- TL_Type (type of operation / function in the program)
- TL_SubType (sub-type of operation)
- EntityID1
- EntityID2
- EntityID3 ...
- TL_Message (message relating to operation)
- TL_Error_No
- TL_Error_Source
- TL_TableName
- TL_RecID
- TL_Prior_Value (value before operation)
- TL_New_Value (value after operation)
- TL_FormName
- TL_FieldName
- TL_CreatedUser
- TL_CreatedDAte
- TL_ModifiedUser (Seems like it would be for keeping track of an optimistic lock)
- TL_ModifiedDate (Seems like it would be for keeping track of an optimistic lock)

I've seen tables like this before, and I know you can find out the actions of users in the database from them.  But I don't know this sort of table is called exactly.

Comment: Alright give me a downvote, but at least answer my question.

Comment: Sounds like a general auditing table to me.  I assume this is something that was built into your application and isn't provided by your RDBMS automatically?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: I just want to make sure I have the terminology right because from what I understand a transaction table or transaction log are completely different from this, and have to do with the inner-workings of the database and ACID.

Comment: The proper name of this auditing table may be specific to the application/vendor. You're thinking in the context of the app not the actual database, so just don't confuse the two.

Comment: @JohnM Okay I've seen tables like it in other apps before, I just wondered if there was a general name for it...or several general names for it.